# Реализация фильтрации данных в контроллере

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Раньше делал фильтрации данных в Get методе контроллера через swith, потом мне сказали что это не очень правильно и что в ASP.net есть правильная реализация данного процесса. Я вообще забыл то о чем мне сказали  поэтому не могу нагуглить. Дайте пожалуйста ссылку на статью или подскажите как называется этот механизм

Comment: Вы что то где то делали, потом вам кто то что то сказал, но вы забыли. Теперь вы просите вам напомнить о том, что вы забыли, а мы не знали. Я верно понимаю?

Comment: @tym32167 когда идет обращение к API контроллеру с целью получить данный но с определенной фильтрацией, например продукты только красного цвета, то я использовал swith чтобы выполнить логику по той фильтрации которая необходима. Вопрос:как правильно реализовывать данное дело в asp. Я записал то что мне советовали но записи потерялись, однако очень нужно это узнать

Comment: вы просто повторили текст из вопроса, тут нет новой информации. Добавьте свой код в вопрос.

Comment: [Filters in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0) - может, это имелось в виду